# What is the best algorithm to join and process many records in database?

Tags: sql-server, database, architecture

- I have db1 with table1 (200k-400k, in future 700K-800K, but not soon) and db2 with table2 (1M - 2M, and increases by 500K-700K per year).
- I need to process all records in db1.table1 and for each record I need to execute subquery in db2.table2.
- Records processing should be concurrently in several threads on application server.

I think about two strategies:

1. Join tables (or select with subquery), save to temp table and iterate from application server.
2. Iterate db1.table1 from application server and execute subquery for each row (or for batch).

What is the best way and why?

Comment: What kind of "processing" are you talking about? What kind of subquery to you have to execute in the other table?

Comment: Execute business and application logic, for example, calculate and store result in db or send notifications... Subquery is simple select with predicate.

Comment: Subquery returns several rows for each row of main table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sake of performance, you should create single query joining these 2 tables.

If your tables reside on different servers, [create database link](http://dba010.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/how-to-create-database-link-in-sql-server-2005/) between them, or, better yet, refactor your setup such that your tables are part of the same database.

In any case, be sure to create appropriate indexes and run your queries through `EXPLAIN PLAN` to find possible bottlenecks and avoid sequential scans.